# .bat file that will start a process, get its PID, monitor its running condition

Tags: batch-file

I am basically trying to write a script on WIN10 that will allow me to start a python script, monitor for it to complete before moving on the next step.  This looks like it should work but it just loops at the 2s timer, even after I close the notepad windows.  This is kind of a combination of 2 scripts I found on here so I may be way out to lunch on my methods.

```
       @echo off
set PROCESSNAME=notepad.exe

::First save current pids with the wanted process name
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "RETPIDS="
set "OLDPIDS=p"
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='%PROCESSNAME%'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do (set "OLDPIDS=!OLDPIDS!%%ap")

::Spawn new process(es)
start %PROCESSNAME%

::Check and find processes missing in the old pid list
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='%PROCESSNAME%'" get ProcessID ^| findstr [0-9]') do (
if "!OLDPIDS:p%%ap=zz!"=="%OLDPIDS%" (set "RETPIDS=/PID %%a !RETPIDS!")
)

:check
set stillalive=no
for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ('tasklist') do (
set pid=%%b
if !pid! == %RETPIDS% (
set stillalive=yes
)
)
if %stillalive% == yes (
cls
 echo/Oh! He's still there, I'll wait.
 timeout /t 2 /nobreak
 goto check
) else (
 echo/He's not there anymore, start the party!!
)
pause>nul
```

If there is a simpler way of doing this that's fine, if I can get this working with notepad, it should be easy to adapt to suit my needs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think `set pid=%%` will do? Hint: You are **not using** `%%b`

Comment: oops that's a mistake from when I was messing around with it trying to get it to work.  %% is supposed to be %%b.  I fixed it up

Comment: So fix up your question.

Comment: `if !pid! == %RETPIDS% (
set stillalive=yes
)` should probably be inside the previous `for` loop, otherwise you are only checking the pid of the last task in the tasklist.

Comment: I changed my question.  Did you mean like that?

Comment: Yes. Does it work now? Note I'm away from home so won't be able to answer again for a few hours.

Comment: No it still loops at the 2s timer.  I plan on removing the 2s.  I was just trying to give a visual cue as to where the code was failing.  If you can try the code you should be able to see it too.  It should be able to run on any windows PC

Answer (score 0):

It's necro, I know, but I looked for something similar and just ended up here. This did a trick and fixed the script:

Replace

`(set "RETPIDS=/PID %%a !RETPIDS!")`

with

`(set "RETPIDS=%%a!RETPIDS!")`

The thing is that `RETPIDS` value looked like `/PID 18465` and `pid` value was like `18465` and there also was a mess up with `!!`, `%%`, `"%%"` stuff and condition therefore strangely triggered every time although it obviously shouldn't.

Also seems that yours `RETPIDS` implies a possibility of several PIDs in one string like `"5147 8463 6521"` but it defenitely won't work with your single `!pid!` comparison in a loop.